# Subscriber gets no messages

Tags: ros, rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am almost going crazy ... I analyse a bag file and monitor a strange behaviour.
When I use the code below I have to comment one of rospy.Subscriber(...) lines. Otherwise the Program gets no message and rxgraph shows no connection. But with only one subscriber (regardless of which) the code works well!

What is wrong in my idea?

Best wishes from Germany
Enjoy the weekend

Poseidonius

```
import roslib; roslib.load_manifest('Localization')
import rospy
from std_msgs.msg import Float32

def callback(event, index):
     print index

rospy.init_node('OdoMapper')
rospy.Subscriber("/OdoLeft", Float32, callback, 0) # one of them have to be commented
rospy.Subscriber("/OdoRight", Float32, callback, 1)  
rospy.spin()
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10836/subscriber-gets-no-messages/) by [Poseidonius](https://answers.ros.org/users/248/poseidonius/) on ROS Answers with karma: 427 on 2011-08-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2011-08-08**:
Another test, just to verify: Does this only happen on the bag file? If you do 2x rostopic pub, does everything work OK?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2011-08-08**:
Strange, indeed. Although I don't use Fedora, I would assume that it is not Fedora itself, but the system setup. Can you check the network setup tfoote posted below even on the local machine?

**Comment by [Poseidonius](https://answers.ros.org/users/248/poseidonius/) on 2011-08-08**:
Strange  - on a Ubuntu PC the code works fine, just my Fedora presents the mentioned behaviour

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-08-06**:
Can you add the output of roswtf to your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

no activity in a month, closing

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-09-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0